# Customize Custom Post Type URL

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

Actually I needs to change the structure of my urls for the custom post type ( I also want to customise taxonomy url but only targeting post for this question to avoid confusion)

My custom post type is Property having slug `properties` and it have a taxonomy 'Property Category' having slug `property_category`

## Requirement

Currently the structure of custom post type is as follow:
`https://domain.com/properties/postname`

For custom post type I want to include categories and sub categories in the url and remove `properties` slug like
`https://domain.com/property_category/property_sub_category/**/postname`

By using the plugin (Custom Post Type Permalinks) I am able to get this url `https://domain.com/properties/property_category/property_sub_category/**/postname`

As you see that my above url have `properties` in it and I have to remove it so everything is working fine till here for me.

After that, I have removed the properties from url and add function to check my property custom post type along with posts and pages so my url becomes `https://domain.com/property_category/sub_category/**/postname` but it breaks means giving me 404.

This url is working but I didn't need this one `https://domain.com/property_postname`

I believes that Wordpress `ReWrite API` can solve this problem but unable to figure out the actual solution for it.

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems that I face is already described in detail. As I guess that wordpress rewrite api can solve this problem so I have found that solution. I only have two main category for my posts so I map those to my properties because as I am removing custom_post_type name from url so there should be something to identify and map the url.

```
/**
 * Rewriting url
 */
function mak_rewrite_add_rewrites()
{

    // Mapping Property
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^category_one_name(/[\S]*)+(/[\S]*)$',
        'index.php?property=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );

    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^category_two_name(/[\S]*)+(/[\S]*)$',
        'index.php?property=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'mak_rewrite_add_rewrites');
```

`$matches[2]` represents to get value from second parenthesis in regular expression.